# Bucardo installation postgres plperl not available

Tags: postgresql, replication

During Bucardo installation (bucardo_ctl install) i received this error.

```
Installation cannot proceed unless the Pl/PerlU language is available
```

It is weird because i have installed postgres-plperl-9.3 package (I have postgres-9.3).

Comment: Have you tried creating a test database and enabling pl/perlu to see if it works?

Answer (score 1):

It help when i drop bucardo database in postgresql. It was required for me because first installation failed.

```
dropdb bucardo
bucardo_ctl install
```